# $f$ absolutely continuous and $f'\in L^3[0,1]$, which values of $\alpha $ does $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+} x^{-\alpha}f(x)=0$?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces, absolute-continuity

I'm working my way through some old analysis quals at my university and I came across this question. Let $f$ be absolutely continuous on $[0,1]$ with $f(0)=0$ and $f'\in L^3([0,1])$. For which values of $\alpha$ does
$$ \lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+} x^{-\alpha}f(x)=0$$
for all such $f$?

I have tried the following approach. Using the FTOC for Lebesgue integrals and Holder's inequality: $x^{-\alpha}f(x)=\int_0^xf'(t)x^{-\alpha}dt\leq ||\chi_{[0,x]}|f'(t)|^3||_{3,[0,1]}x^{-\alpha/3}$. The quanitity on the right hand side will go to zero if $\alpha>0$. So this doens't seem to be super helpful. How should I proceed?

Comment: Use Hoelder's inequality in the form $|\int_0^x f'(t) dt| \le \|f'\|_{L^3} x^{2/3}$.

Comment: You made a mistake using Holder's inequality.  Do it like @HansEngler did it, but keep the $\|f'\chi_{[0,x]}\|_3$.

Comment: Does this proof check out? Using the FOTC for Lesbeuge integrals $(f(x)=\int_0^xf'(t)dt \textrm{ and }f'\in L^1)$ and Holder's inequality (exponents 3 and 3/2). We get
$
    |f(x)|=\Big|\int_0^x f'(t)dt\Big|\leq \int_0^x |f'(t)|dt\leq ||f'||_3||\chi_{[0,x]}||_{3/2}=||f'||_3x^{2/3}
$
Thus $|x^{-\alpha}f(x)|\leq  ||f'||_3 x^{2/3-\alpha}\rightarrow 0$ if $\alpha<2/3$

Comment: Yes @MEG What is harder seems to be showing what happens when $\alpha =2/3$.

Comment: Any hints on how to start the $\alpha=2/3$ or the $\alpha>2/3$ case?

Comment: For $\alpha = 2/3$, you can still use $\|f'\|_{L^3(0,x)} \to 0$ as $x \to 0$. For $\alpha > 2/3$, you just have to find an $f$ with $f' \in L^3$ such that the limit is not 0 or does not exist. Try $f(x) = x^\beta$ for a suitable $\beta$.